# Is 'using' appropriate in a context where there is nothing to dispose?

Tags: c#, .net, code-quality, readability

In C#, `using` statement is used to dispose in a deterministic manner the resources without waiting for garbage collector. For example, it may be used to:

- Dispose SQL commands or connections,
- Close streams, freeing the underlying source like a file,
- Free GDI+ elements,
- etc.

I noticed that `using` is used more and more in cases where there is nothing to dispose, but where it's just more convenient for the caller to write a `using` block rather than two separate commands.

Examples:

- [MiniProfiler](http://miniprofiler.com/), written by Stack Overflow team, uses `using` to denote blocks to profile:

  ```
  using (profiler.Step("Name goes here"))
  {
      this.DoSomethingUseful(i - 1);
  }
  ```

  One alternative approach would be to have two blocks:

  ```
  var p = profiler.Start("Name goes here");
  this.DoSomethingUseful(i - 1);
  profiler.Stop(p);
  ```

  Another approach would be to use actions:

  ```
  profiler.Step("Name goes here", () => this.DoSomethingUseful(i - 1));
  ```
- ASP.NET MVC also picked `using` for forms:

  ```
  <% using (Html.BeginForm())
     { %>
         <label for="firstName">Name:</label>
         <%= Html.TextBox("name")%>
         <input type="submit" value="Save" />    
  <% } %>
  ```

**Is such usage appropriate?** How to justify it, given that there are several drawbacks:

- Beginners would be lost, since such usage doesn't correspond to the one which is explained in books and language specification,
- The code should be expressive. Here, the expressiveness suffers, since the appropriate usage of `using` is to show that behind, there is a resource, like a stream, a network connection or a database which should be released without waiting the garbage collector.

Comment: The approach of having two individual statements suffers from the same problem as naive resource management without `using`: The latter statement (e.g. `profiler.Stop(p)`) is not guaranteed to be executed in the face of exceptions and control flow.

Comment: @delnan: this explains why MiniProfiler avoided the second approach. But the second one should be avoided in all cases, since it's difficult to write and maintain.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9472304

Comment: See also http://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7363826#7363826

Comment: `using` is error and exception safe. It ensures `Dispose` will be called irregardless of any mistakes the programmer makes. That is why it is so common.

Comment: @MathewFoscarini: A good argument for *not* using it in places where throwing an exception should *prevent* the Dispose behavior from occurring.  Stopping a profile timer? Probably good; timer should always stop.  `</form>` tag placement?  Maybe, maybe not.

Comment: @RobertHarvey that's an interesting thought. Can you give an example of where this might be an issue?

Comment: @RobertHarvey agreed, `using` to open/close tags is very strange. I've not seen that before.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101524 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1095438

Comment: Related: http://grabbagoft.blogspot.com/2007/06/example-of-creating-scope-with-using.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your last statement - that "the appropriate usage of using is to show that behind, there is a resource, like a stream, a network connection or a database which should be released without waiting the garbage collector" is incorrect, and the reason why is given at the documentation for the IDisposable interface: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx

> The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources.

So, if your class uses any unmanaged resouces, it doesn't matter when you may or may not want GC to happen - it's got nothing whatsoever to do with GC as unmanaged resources aren't GC'ed (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3607213/what-is-meant-by-managed-vs-unmanaged-resources-in-net).

So the purpose of "using" is not to avoid waiting on GC, it's to force a release of those unmanaged resources *now*, before the class instance goes out of scope and it's Finalize is called.  This is important for reasons that should be obvious - an unmanaged resource may have dependencies on other unmanaged resources, and if they are disposed of (or finalized) in the wrong order Bad Things may happen.

So if the class being instanced in the using block uses any unmanaged resources, then then answer is yes - it is appropriate.

Note that IDisposable is not prescriptive about it being *only* for releasing unmanaged resources, however - just that this is it's *primary* purpose.  It *may* be the case that the author of the class has some action that they want to enforce happening at a certain time, and implementing IDisposable may be a way of getting that to happen, but whether or not that's an elegant solution is something that can only be answered on a case-by-case basis.

Whichever, the use of "using" implies that the class implements IDisposable, so it doesn't violate code expressiveness; it makes it quite clear what's going on, in fact.

Comment: "The primary use of this interface is to release unmanaged resources." I say Microsoft's documentation sucks on that point. Maybe that's how *they* use it in the FCL, but application developers have been using it for a variety of things for close to a decade now - some for good reasons, some for not-so-good reasons. But quoting that chunk of their doc does not answer the OP's question at all.

Comment: Note my second last para - the *primary* purpose need not be the *only* purpose.  IDisposable can be implemented for any reason whatsoever, and it provides a known interface with expected behaviour and usage style, so when you see it you know that there's something else that needs to happen before the instance can just be let go out of scope.  The point is: if it implements IDisposable, then using is appropriate; everything else is just preamble.

Comment: You're basically saying the purpose is not avoid waiting for GC, it's avoid waiting for the finalizer. But I don't see the difference: finalizer is called by the GC.

Comment: The GC operates in a non-deterministic manner - you don't know when it will be called.  The GC also just calls the finalizer, but it doesn't do any disposing itself - the actual resource itself is outside of the GC's control.  With using (1) the object is properly scoped, and (2) the disposal is known to happen at a known point in time - when it exits the scope of the using block, the unmanaged resource is gone (or - worst case - handed over to something else that will destroy it).  Really, this is just nitpicking; read the documentation, it's all there are shouldn't need to be repeated.

Answer (score 8):

The use of `using` implies the presence of a `Dispose()` method.  Other programmers will assume that such a method exists on the object.  Consequently, if an object is not disposable, you should not use `using` on it.

Code clarity is king. Either omit the `using`, or implement `IDisposable` on the object.

MiniProfiler appears to be using `using` as a mechanism to "fence in" the code being profiled.   There is some merit to this; presumably, MiniProfiler is either calling `Dispose()` to stop a timer, or the timer is stopped when the MiniProfiler object goes out of scope.

More generally, you would invoke`using` when some sort of finalization needs to occur automatically.  The documentation for [`html.BeginForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.108).aspx) states that, when the method is used in a `using` statement,  it renders the closing `</form>` tag at the end of the `using` block.

That doesn't necessarily mean it's still not abuse.

Comment: So far so obvious. The question is, when (if at all) is it appropriate to implement `IDisposable`/`Dispose()` despite not having anything to dispose in the sense OP is describing?

Comment: I thought I made that clear; there *isn't* a time when that is appropriate.

Comment: My point is, `Dispose` is required for `using` to make sense at all (regardless of whether it's appropriate). OP's examples all implement `Dispose`, don't they? And IIUC, the question is whether it is correct that these classes use `Dispose`, rather than some other method (like `Stop()` for MiniProfiler).

Comment: @delnan: Presumably, MiniProfiler implements `IDisposable`, using the `Dispose()` method to call `Stop()`.  While the convention for `using` implies the freeing of certain resources, it is apparent that this is not always the context in which it is used.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not the question. The question is whether it's a good idea to do so.

Comment: @delnan: Again, I thought I made that clear.  If it makes the intent of your code clearer, then it's a good idea.  If it doesn't, it isn't.

Comment: Just to clarify, "The use of `using` **requires** the presence of a `Dispose()` method via the `IDispose` interface."  At least, this is the case in .Net.

Comment: @Hand-E-Food: Some programmers use `using` without fully understanding the underlying plumbing.  The documentation for `Html.BeginForm` doesn't even state that it returns an `IDisposable`, only that it renders the closing `</form>` tag if you wrap it in a `using` statement.

Comment: @RobertHarvey, I see what you're saying.  I was suggesting that if the `using` code compiles, then the objecet is guaranteed to be disposable.  As you say, disposing can be as simple as writing a closing HTML tag.

Answer (score 1):

`using` is error and exception safe. It ensures `Dispose()` will be called irregardless of any mistakes the programmer makes. It does not interfere with the catching or handling of exceptions, but the `Dispose()` method is executed recursively up the stack when an exception is thrown.

Objects that implement `IDispose` but have nothing to dispose when they are done. Are at best, future proofing their design. So that you don't have to refactor your source code, when in the future, they then need to dispose of something.